# WiX installer and redistribution of libstdc++6.dll from MinGW

Tags: dll, wix, version

I am building a MSI installer with WiX for redistributing my MinGW64 application. This requires to ship MinGW dlls with the executable.

The libstdc6.dll file is not versionned. What is the cleanest approach for this?

I have tried:

1. Adding a companion file to the dll component, pointing to the main app exe, which is versionned. However, wix complains that I cannot set a companion to a dll
2. Putting the dll in the main app exe component, but this is discouraged in every wix faq, howto and forum...
3. Adding attribute `DefaultVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.mainapp.exe)"` to the dll file element for overriding the (missing) dll version. This seems to work at first glance, but wix is issuing warnings related to this:

> C:\Users\Etienne\Documents\coding\ocean\ocean.wxs(116) : warning
>   LGHT1103 : The DefaultVersion '!(bind.FileVersion.mainapp.exe)' was used
>   for file 'libstdc6.dll' which has no version. No entry for this file
>   will be placed in the MsiFileHash table. For unversioned files,
>   specifying a version that is different from the actual file may result
>   in unexpected versioning behavior during a repair or while patching.
>   Version the resource to eliminate this warning.

What is the best way to solve this?

Thanks,

Etienne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, your best bet is option #2. All the rules assume that executable code would be properly versioned and thus are best deployed as KeyPaths of their respective Components. Since the .dll is not versioned, placing it as a data file with a versioned file is the next best thing.

Although, for the record, versioning the .dll is by far the most optimal solution. :)

Comment: Thanks!
Fully agree, but I won't recompile libstdc++ just for adding versionning... I have tried finding a tool for adding it by hand to the dll, but it seems that none are able to modify 64-bit gcc binaries (different format?)